# Add custom errors to vee validator(ErrorBag)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

Is it possible to add custom errors into the ErrorBag

I am using nuxtjs. i have registered vee-validate into my plugin via nuxt.config.js

It works fine However

I want to use the same error code within the template

ex:

```
 <template>
   <div v-if="errors.all().length>0">
       //loop through
   </div>
 </template>
```

i am using axios to fetch user information. 
if the request doesnt return my expected data set. i was thinking i could simply

```
 this.errors.push('this is my error message') //-> or some variant of this
```

When i do this i get that this.errors.push is not a function

I know that

```
this.errors = ErrorBag{ __ob__: Observer} //-> has items and a vmId attributes
```

If i amend the code to push onto ErrorBag i get push of undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is documented in the API of ErrorBag. You can add custom messages such as:

```
// For example, you may want to add an error related to authentication:
errors.add({
  field: 'auth',
  msg: 'Wrong Credentials'
});
```

Check the documentation here for more info: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/api/errorbag.html

Comment: That link is broken

Comment: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/api/errorbag.html

Comment: does anyone know how to do this in vee validate v4 for vue3

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I see it here, please search "errorBag"
https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/use-form/